# Reverse of words of a given string in C using user defined functions

Tags: c, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

The code is not working it didn't give accurate results. I don't know where is the problem or miss coding? 
My input and output:

```
Enter a sentence :
hello im here to help you
heleh im here to help you
```

I used the following code,

```
int main()
{
    /*
    Enter a sentence to get reverse of each word
    hello this is CPROGRAM Enjoy Programming
    olleh siht si MARGORPC yojnE gnimmargorP
    */
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter a sentence : \n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    revwords(str);
    fputs(str, stdout);
    return 0;
}
void revwords(char* str){
    int i = 0;
    for(int j=1;str[j] != '\0';j++){
        if( str[j] == ' ' || str[j] == '\t' || str[j] == '\n'){
            rev(str, i, j-1);
            i = j+1;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
void rev(char* str, int from, int to){
    char temp;
    for(int i=from;i<= to/2;i++){
        temp = str[i];
        str[to-i] = str[i];
        str[to-i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: The swapping is broken: `str[to-i] = str[i];` => `str[i] = str[to-i];`

Comment: Thank you but still not working

Comment: I'm at all ears

Comment: FYI: you can use [`isspace()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isspace.3p.html) or [`isblank()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isblank.3p.html) to check for spaces/blanks instead of checking each character by hand (`' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Your `rev` function is broken in multiple ways:

```
void rev(char* str, int from, int to){
    char temp;
    for(int i=from;i<= to/2;i++){
        temp = str[i];
        str[to-i] = str[i];
        str[to-i] = temp;
    }
}
```

First: Your swapping is broken. You assign to `str[to-i]` twice and never in the other direction.

```
void rev(char* str, int from, int to){
    char temp;
    for(int i=from;i<= to/2;i++){
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[to-i];
        str[to-i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Then your index is not calculated correct.
You seem to try to reverse from `from` to `to` but you treat `to` as if it was a length.
You need to use a separate index:

```
void rev(char* str, int from, int to){
    char temp;
    for(int i=0; i <= (to-from)/2; i++){
        temp = str[from+i];
        str[from+i] = str[to-i];
        str[to-i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Otherwise if you reverse from 10..15 you will copy to index 5..0 instead of 15..10

Comment: @OvaisKhanday Please be precise what is exactly not working. Nobody can read your mind.

Comment: Try using ```(to-from)2``` instead of ```(from-to) /2```

Comment: Fixed typo. Try again please. If it is still not working, pelase add updated version to the question (don't delete old version)  and add new input/output.

Comment: You code worked fine I just changed the condition in for loop...```void rev(char* str, int from, int to){
    char temp;
    for(int i=0; i <= (to-from)/2; i++){
        temp = str[from+i];
        str[from+i] = str[to-i];
        str[to-i] = temp;
    }
}```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
   {
    /*
    Enter a sentence to get reverse of each word
    hello this is CPROGRAM Enjoy Programming
    olleh siht si MARGORPC yojnE gnimmargorP
    */
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter a sentence : \n");

    //fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str);

    revwords(str);

    //fputs(str, stdout);
    printf("%s\n",str);

    return 0;
}
void revwords(char* str){
    int i = 0;
    for(int j=1;str[j] != '\0';j++){
        if( str[j] == ' ' || str[j] == '\t' || str[j] == '\n'){
            rev(str, i, j-1);
            i = j+1;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
void rev(char* str, int from, int to){
    char temp;
    while(from <= to){
        temp = str[from];
        str[from] = str[to];
        str[to] = temp;
        from++;
        to--;
    }
}
```

You can try this code. In your code in rev function swap is not done with correct way. And for input a line you can use `scanf("%[^\n]s", str);`.

**Another bug in your code you are not reverse the last word. so outside the for loop in your revwords function need to reverse the last word.**  **which is not fix this code, try yourself and if not able to find then please comment.**

```
void revwords(char* str){
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    for(j=1;str[j] != '\0';j++){
        if( str[j] == ' ' || str[j] == '\t' || str[j] == '\n'){
            rev(str, i, j-1);
            i = j+1;
            j++;
        }
    }
    rev(str,i,j-1);
}
```

Change with this block of code and hope it will solve. it's just a modified version of your code.

Comment: Why should the OP use `scanf` without length limit instead of a `fgets`?

Comment: Your loop may run riot accessing tons of memory out of bounds: `while(from!=to)` will never be false for an even length to reverse.

Comment: Thanks ! now i fix the while conditon.

Comment: Are you aware that you made the problem regarding last word worse? The OP used `fgets´ which keeps the `\n` in the buffer unless the input is too long. This is handled fine in the loop and the last word will be reversed. Only in this case the last word will be missed. On the other hand your approach will not contain the `\n` causing the word to be missed. Your code might even cause a segmentation fault in this case and at least fail to reverse the last word. That's not really an improvement. :( Maybe you should stick to the rule "Don't fix what is not broken" at least for the input part.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. it will help for my next answer.

Answer (score 0):

The both functions, `rev` and `revwords`, are incorrect.

For example in general the user can pass an empty string. In this case the function `revwords` invokes undefined behavior due to the initial condition in the for loop

```
for(int j=1;str[j] != '\0';j++){
```

Also if the passed string does not contain white spaces that is it contains only one word then nothing will be reversed.

In the function `rev` the condition of the loop is incorrect

```
for(int i=from;i<= to/2;i++){
```

For example if `form` is equal to `3` and `to` is equal to `5` then the expression `i <= to/2` yields `2` and the loop will never be executed.

Apart from this the code that swaps characters

```
    temp = str[i];
    str[to-i] = str[i];
    str[to-i] = temp;
```

is also incorrect.

And at least the function `revwords` should have the return type `char *` following the convention of standard C string functions.

Take into account that the function `fgets` can append the new line character to the entered string. You should remove it.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the functions can be implemented. I only renamed the function names.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

static char * reverse( char *s, size_t n ) 
{ 
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ ) 
    { 
        char c = s[ i ]; 
        s[ i ] = s[ n - i - 1 ]; 
        s[ n - i - 1 ] = c; 
    } 

    return s; 
} 

char * reverse_by_words( char *s ) 
{ 
    const char *delim = " \t\n"; 

    char *p = s; 

    while ( *p ) 
    { 
        p += strspn( p, delim ); 

        if ( *p ) 
        { 
            char *q = p; 

            p += strcspn( p, delim ); 

            reverse( q, p - q ); 
        } 
    } 

    return s; 
} 

int main(void)  
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char s[N];

    printf( "Enter a sentence: " );

    fgets( s, N, stdin );   

    //  remove the appended new line character '\n'
    s[ strcspn( s, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    puts( s ); 

    puts( reverse_by_words( s ) ); 

    return 0; 
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a sentence: hello im here to help you
hello im here to help you
olleh mi ereh ot pleh uoy
```

Comment: Why do you assume an input without spaces will not be reversed? Unless the `\n` doesn't fit into the buffer it will trigger reversing the word. It should not be removed therefore.

Comment: @Gerhardh The user can supply any string. It is only fgets can append the new line character and can not append depending on how long the entered sequence of characters. So the function is invalid.